Does osm2po take into consideration one-ways, bridges, tunnels, underpasses and overpasses?
I've started with osm and pgrouting recently, and found osm2po to be a great tool, however I can't find any information about how it processes osm data. I use pgr_dijkstra to create a route and use directed flag, but my route goes over oncoming traffic and drives off from a ramp over oncoming way. So I can't figure out if I'm using osm2po wrongly, or osm2po doesn't take into consideration levels and directions or I'm building the route wrongly.

can you share what you have tried to do so far?
